# how to modify this single thread into multithreading in c# .net

Tags: c#, windows-services

hi here am using single threading in c#.net, let me explain you how it is working now if suppose job A is running in a long process until unless it job A was completed it will not go for job B, but here requirement is all the jobs should gets activated but none of the jobs get intrupted so how can i modify this threading, can any give some suggestions please asap

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    strNowDate = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    timerjob.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(CsvGenFromDatabase);
    timerjob.Interval = Convert.ToDouble(DueTime);
    timerjob.Enabled = true;
    eventLog1.WriteEntry("my service started");
}
protected override void OnStop()
{
    strNowDate = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    eventLog1.WriteEntry("my service stopped");
}
private void CsvGenFromDatabase(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timerjob.stop();
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew)) // Transaction Scope Started  
    {
        Thread threadITD = new Thread(new ThreadStart(FileGenerationForITD));  // Thread Initialize for ITD
        Thread threadCTD = new Thread(new ThreadStart(FileGenerationForCTD));  // Thread Initialize for CTD
        Thread threadCID = new Thread(new ThreadStart(FileGenerationForCID));  // Thread Initialize for CID
        Thread threadFFM = new Thread(new ThreadStart(FileGenerationForFFM));  // Thread Initialize for FFM
        try      
        {                
            if ((threadITD == null) ||
                (threadITD.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Stopped) ||
                (threadITD.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Unstarted))
            {
                threadITD.Start();  // Thread Started for ITD
            }                  
            if ((threadCTD == null) ||
                (threadCTD.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Stopped) ||
                (threadCTD.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Unstarted))
            {
                threadCTD.Start(); // Thread Started for CTD
            }
            if ((threadCID == null) ||
                (threadCID.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Stopped) ||
                (threadCID.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Unstarted))
            {
                threadCID.Start(); // Thread Started for CID
            }                  
            if ((threadFFM == null) ||
                (threadFFM.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Stopped) ||
                (threadFFM.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Unstarted))
            {
                threadFFM.Start(); // Thread Started for FFM
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            objErrorLog.SrtErrorText = ex.ToString().Substring(0, 25);
            objErrorLog.StrErrorDescription = ex.ToString();
            objErrorLog.WriteErrorLog(objErrorLog);
        }
        finally
        {
            scope.Complete();
        }
    }
    timerjob.start();
}
```

Comment: @MitchWheat - That is all that can be said...

Comment: @ M.Babcock kindly help me out for change it as into multithreading,i am new to this window service

Comment: @pravz - While this is only one of the many obvious problems with the code you posted, let me introduce you to the [BackgroundWorker](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/112547-using-the-backgroundworker-in-c%23/).

Comment: You... don't seem to understand what your code is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to already be multi-threaded.  Try adding logging code to the start and end of each `FileGenerationForXXX` method so you can see the four methods starting together and stopping separately.

```
private void FileGenerationForITD()
{
    eventlog1.WriteEntry("FileGenerationForITD started.");
    ...
    eventlog1.WriteEntry("FileGenerationForITD finished.");
}
```

Additionally, you can knock out all of the `if` statements.  The thread objects are guaranteed to be in that state because nothing changed between `new` and `Start()`.

```
Thread threadITD = new Thread(new ThreadStart(FileGenerationForITD));
Thread threadCTD = new Thread(new ThreadStart(FileGenerationForCTD));
// ...
try
{
    ThreadITD.Start();
    ThreadCTD.Start();
    // ...
}
```

**EDIT:** In response to comments.

To prevent the timer from triggering a second time before the threads all complete, I suggest joining the threads before starting the timer again.  `Thread.Join()` causes this thread to sleep until the referenced thread has ended.  All other threads contiunue uninterrupted.

```
private void CsvGenFromDatabase(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timerjob.stop();

    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
    {
        Thread threadITD = new Thread(new ThreadStart(FileGenerationForITD));
        Thread threadCTD = new Thread(new ThreadStart(FileGenerationForCTD));
        Thread threadCID = new Thread(new ThreadStart(FileGenerationForCID));
        Thread threadFFM = new Thread(new ThreadStart(FileGenerationForFFM));

        threadITD.Start();
        threadCTD.Start();
        threadCID.Start();
        threadFFM.Start();

        threadITD.Join();
        threadCTD.Join();
        threadCID.Join();
        threadFFM.Join();

        scope.Complete();
    }

    timerjob.start();  
}
```

Comment: can you please explain little brief,but i am checking when the thread is null or stopped at such conditions only i am sayng to start the thread

Comment: Look at just one thread, say threadITD.  Firstly, you’ve declared `threadITD = new Thread(...)`, and shortly later tested for `threadITD == null`.  How can `threadITD` become null in the mean time?  It can’t, so that test is meaningless.  Secondly, a `new Thread` has the default `ThreadState = Unstarted`.  How can this change?  Only by calling `threadITD.Start()` or `threadITD.Abort()`.  Neither of these are called before you test the `ThreadState`, so the result of the test is already known.  Basically, your `if` statement tests for guaranteed and known conditions, and therefore is redundant.

Comment: because in mean time if another instance starts up then , existing thread should not be disturbed right so i have did like that, am checking before threadITD==null such conditions, okay if i am wrong means i will as such you said, but my doubt if i update as your reply above said assume if one instance has started still job is pending  mean time another instance start by timer event, hence first instance will it effected ?

Comment: If the timer triggers a second time, and the first threads are not complete, then yes, it will start four new threads.  Because your threads are declared as local variables, they are "forgotten" every time the CsvGenFromDatabase method exits.  See my edits above.